# I can't enable or disable modules. I'm getting "An error occurred while saving this configuration"

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have a new fairly fresh install of Magento 1.7.0.2. I installed two custom payment method modules that are working fine. But now whenever I try to disable or enable any Payment Method or Shipping Method it gives me an error like this:

> An error occurred while saving this configuration: Warning:
>   preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in
>   /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/Encrypted.php
>   on line 57

Do you have any idea why?

EDIT 2:

I found the problem. It was caused by a patch I applied to fix to a previous BUG. :P

EDIT:

So I disabled all custom modules and I was still getting the same error. I logged what was happening and it seems that some core modules are sending an array to be saved.

Like PayPal Express Checkout for instance. One of the config options is the Time of Day in the SFTP credentials for Settlement Report Settings. It's composed by three different drop-downs and it's sending an array to be saved!

In the Shipping Methods, UPS has a config options called Allowed Methods, and it's also sending an array!

I still don't know why it wasn't happening before and now it is. They shouldn't be encrypting everything. Any clues?

Comment: In my case I get this error only **locally**, i.e. my **remote copy** of the website (production) **works**. I get it only when trying to enable/disable _a module_ from the backend.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, its a known bug, try this around line no. 135 on code/core/mage/Adminhtml/model/config/data.php

```
// add this code
$backendClass=false;
if (isset($fieldConfig->backend_model)) {
    $backendClass = $fieldConfig->backend_model;
}  // before this
if (!$backendClass) {
    $backendClass = 'core/config_data';
}
```

Comment: The above worked for me in Magento 1.7.0.2, but be sure to comment out $backendClass = $fieldConfig->backend_model; which was for me on line 135 as this is is the line that causes the error.

Answer (score 2):

This actually is a reported bug in Magento that seems to affect encrypted config settings (passwords, API keys, etc.).

http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue?issue=14217

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling the first of the modules, log out of the admin panel, clear /var/cache and see if the problem still exists. If it does, do the same with the second module.

The problem should be gone. Now that you know which module causes the problems you can either decide to try another module instead or debug to see whats going wrong.

Put a breakpoint on line 57 in  /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/Encrypted.php to see what goes wrong. It seems that the second parameter is not a string (might be null for example due to wrong configuration or something) when its given to the preg_match function. Maybe this helps you to identify the problem.

Regards

Comment: Even after disabling the custom modules I'm still getting the errors. So I started investigating like you said, and it seems core modules are sending arrays. I updated my question to show what I found.

Answer (score -1):

Disabling modules through the back office isn't a good idea as it only disables the block output, if you would like to disable a module you should go to `app/etc/modules`and there you should find `Module_Name.xml`file - in this file just put `false` in `active` node.